# Not able to move to Parent window after selecting a value in the Child window using selenium

Tags: selenium

I used the below code to switch the window to child window and select a radio-button and switch back to parent window to select few values,but after selecting a value in the child window it doesn't allow me to select a value in the parent window

It says "unable to locate element"

```
fd.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='image22']").click();
String parentwindowRMU=fd.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> handles1=fd.getWindowHandles();
for(String Windowhandles1:handles1)
{
   if(!Windowhandles1.equals(parentwindowRMU))
   {
       fd.switchTo().window(Windowhandles1);   
       Thread.sleep(7000);
       fd.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='radio1']").click();

       fd.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='ext-gen31']").click();
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       break;                       
   }            
}
fd.switchTo().window(parentwindowRMU);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using similar code like this:

1. click on New button

   1. Another window will open to fill up the form
   2. Click on Done button
   3. Now click on Submit button on previous Window
   4. Logout the application

Below is my code:

```
  String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
           for(String windowHandle  : handles)
               {
               if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))
                  {
                  driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
                  driver.findElement(By.id("student_fname1")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("student_fname1")).sendKeys("test");
                driver.findElement(By.id("student_lname1")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("student_lname1")).sendKeys("auto");
                driver.findElement(By.id("student_username1")).clear();
              driver.findElement(By.id("student_username1")).sendKeys("testuser5");
                driver.findElement(By.id("student_password1")).clear();
               driver.findElement(By.id("student_password1")).sendKeys("password");
                new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("student_grade1"))).selectByVisibleText("testvalue");
                driver.findElement(By.name("submit_done")).click();

              driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); //cntrl to parent window

                 driver.findElement(By.className("frm_btn")).click();//button on parent window
                 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();//button on parent window
                  }
               }
```

Use below code and see if it works or not

```
fd.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='image22']").click();
    String parentwindowRMU=fd.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> handles1=fd.getWindowHandles();
    for(String Windowhandles1:handles1)
    {
       if(!Windowhandles1.equals(parentwindowRMU))
       {
           fd.switchTo().window(Windowhandles1);   
           Thread.sleep(7000);
           fd.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='radio1']").click();
    fd.close();
           fd.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='ext-gen31']").click();
           Thread.sleep(5000);

          fd.switchTo().window(parentwindowRMU);
        //code to perform on parent window.         
       }            
    }
```

As per my understanding your code is fine the problem may be of xpath not used properly to locate element on parent window.

Comment: No it is not working..still throwing the same message

Comment: can you please provide some relevant HTML or application URL. because I used to use same technique and it works for me. may be issue is with xpath of element.

Comment: Hi..I am  automating my own application and it wont be accessible to you...How to get relevant HTML?

Comment: Hi My testing scenario is like..I have two Lov values to select i have to select a value from another window and select another value by shifting to another wndow..I cannot write it in the same loop..

Comment: you can use another answer and see it helps or not

Answer (score 0):

Use iterator and a while loop to store the various window handles and then switch back and forth.

```
//Click your link
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
    //Get all the window handles in a set
    Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();
    //iterate through your windows
    while (it.hasNext()){
    String parent = it.next();
    String newwin = it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(newwin);
    //perform actions on new window
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(parent);
                        }
```

Comment: Hi..it is working fine..I have to switch back to the frames which i was missing before..Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iterator for this. A sample example to switch between parent and child windows:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.aplha.co.in/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("alpha")).click();
    Set<String> windowHandlesAfter = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> itAfter = windowHandlesAfter.iterator();

    String parent = itAfter.next();
    String child = itAfter.next();     
    driver.switchTo().window(child);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Ginger Hotel']")).click();
    System.out.println("After clicking on Ginger Hotels on child window");


    Set<String> windowHandlesAfter1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> itAfter1 = windowHandlesAfter1.iterator();

    System.out.println("Printing windowHandles" + driver.getWindowHandles()); 

    parent = itAfter1.next();
    child  = itAfter1.next();
    String child1 = itAfter1.next();

   driver.switchTo().window(child1);
```